# Sql Compact Sync and migration to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-ce, synchronization

Here is our current scenario:
Client App - C# .Net Windows Forms app using .Net 3 and SQL Compact
SQL Database at HQ behind a firewall
Client machines not on the domain, and not always Internet connected

The current process is the user enters data into the app, it is stored in SQL Compact, and SQL Reporting services are used to print reports that get sent in.

We would like to set up Sync so that data from each of the users get's uploaded to the server so reports are no longer necessary.

We have has success setting up sync to copy the users data to the server while on the network behind the firewall. But our users will be in the field disconnected.

We are also looking at migrating the app to Windows 8 in the future. Not necessarily RT, but we would like it to be able to run native on Windows 8 Pro.

Should we stick with SQL Compact? Where can I see a good example of setting up Sync through the firewall or via a web service?

Answer (score 0):

You say "sync" but I wonder if you mean SQL replication. If so, then Yes. SQL CE is still an excellent small, local database for desktop applications (any version of Windows). SQL CE is also the best (if not only) solution to leverage SQL replication.

Now let's pretend you didn't mean SQL replication. The answer is still Yes. SQL CE is a great database for desktop applications. And whatever sync you might have meant is clearly something you already have working. And, it will continue to work.

Because you said `not necessarily RT` you are perfectly safe. CE works on every version of Windows, Windows Mobile (which is deprecated), Phone 7 (not 8), and I hear the forthcoming Embedded Windows, too.

To that end, RT doesn't have SQL CE support (yet, and if ever). RT solutions (the type you would write so you could leverage ARM and the new Win 8 features) have SqlLite as a local storage option. The same is true with Phone 8 +. No question this is in part because they are intended to be connected apps, not local storage apps. A different beast.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks. To clarify what I mean by Sync. The client (Let's say user1) enters his/her data. There data at some point gets updated to the server. User2 enteres his/her data, it gets put on the server. The server has data from both users, but the users only have their own data. Replication or sync?

Comment: Actually, Sql Ce Works fine with Phone 8.

Comment: So, how do I get an offsite client to sync through the firewall to my home database? It's easy in the network, but when I wander... can I still come home?